# how to make sense of People APIs responses?

Tags: error-handling, google-people-api

When calling People API's endpoints, especially in Batch requests, we're getting many different types of error responses.

Some have useful explanation in the error message, like:

> Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Daily Contact Writes (Batch requests
> cost 200 quota)' and limit 'Daily Contact Writes (Batch requests cost
> 200 quota) per day per user' of service 'people.googleapis.com' for
> consumer 'project_number:XXX'.

Which you can detect and properly handle, e.g. wait for 24 hours before retrying that request, but some are more cryptic, such as:

> Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).

This does mention rate-limiting, but for which quota? Is it per-user or per GCP project? When can we retry this?

Note that we're getting this for the first batch call when syncing a user account, so I'm guessing this is not per-user quota, but there's no mention of such rate-limits in the docs.

Specifically, having issues handling:

- "Sync quota exceeded"
- "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)"
- "MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT"

Comment: What requests did you make to get those errors?

Comment: `Resource has been exhausted` happens on `batchCreateContacts` and `batchUpdateContacts` and it might happen on the first such call when syncing a specific user account, so I'm guessing it's not related to one of the declared quotas-per-user-account

Comment: This looks like it could be a bug (specially the `MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT`). I'd create an issue on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). If you paid for a Workspace account, you can also contact [support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I have so far, feel free to edit this answer to add more insights:

Authentication or Google backend issues:

- **"invalid_grant"**: bad access token
- **"Insufficient Permission"**: access token doesn't contain required scope
- **"The service is currently unavailable."**: Google issue
- **"Internal error encountered."**: Google issue
- **"Authentication backend unavailable."**: Google issue

Quota and rate-limiting:

- **"Sync quota exceeded"**: ???
- **"Quota exceeded for quota metric X"**: A specific quota had been exceeded (per min / daily will be part of the message)
- **"Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)"**: ???
- **"MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT"**: ???

Bad requests:

- **"Request contains an invalid argument"**: something is wrong in the request, usually a  Person object with some illegal info item
- **"Request contains a person.etag that is different than the current person.etag"**: An attempt to update a person that was recently updated on Google's side, need to fetch again
- **"Request person.etag is different than the current person.etag"**: same as above
- **"Requested entity was not found"**: An attempt to update a no-longer existing person
- **"Contact person resources are not found"**: same as above
- **"Contact group name is empty, expected to be non empty"**: An attempt to create/update a group with an empty name.
- **"Contact group name already exists"**: An attempt to create a group with the same name

Comment: Contributor @Ddorrance90 has proposed an explanation for the `MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT` in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69215723/3025856). I think that would make more sense as an update to your answer. As I’m not familiar with the API, however, I wanted to give you the opportunity to review it instead of just editing your answer to fill in that gap.

Answer (score 1):

"MY_CONTACTS_OVERFLOW_COUNT" happens when you try to insert contacts to a google account, but they already have the maximum number of contacts.

I am not 100% sure, but this limit seems to be ~20,000 for "normal"/"free" google accounts.

edit- The limit is 25,000, since 2011: https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2011/05/need-more-contacts-in-gmail-contacts.html

Comment: As this is filling in a gap in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68097203/3025856), please suggest this as an edit to that question. This doesn’t offer an answer to the original question. (Or, at least, it’s a very incomplete answer.)